# Filtering Json response updating mongodb database

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, jsonresponse

I'm trying to filter a json response and use the filtered response to update several documents in my mongodb collection. The Json response looks like this:

```
{"88996940":{"charge":"5","start_count":"10","status":"Completed","remains":"90","currency":"USD"},
"88996961":{"charge":"8","start_count":"50","status":"Completed","remains":"50","currency":"USD"},
"88999796":{"charge":"7","start_count":"80","status":"Completed","remains":"20","currency":"USD"}}
```

"88996940","88996961" and "88999796" are the order id's.

I want to filter the values of "start_count", "status" and "remains".

I tried parsing them but it only works if there is only one order id, otherwise the response is "null":

```
JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
orderStartCount = responseObject1["start_count"].ToString();
orderStatus = responseObject1["status"].ToString();
orderRemains = responseObject1["remains"].ToString();
```

I also used the following code to update a single mongodb document but I don't know how to do it with multiple documents and different values.

```
var filterSingle = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("orderID", orderID);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", orderStatus)
                                   .Update.Set("start_count", orderStartCount)
                                   .Update.Set("remains", orderRemains);
MyCollection.UpdateOne(filterSingle, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object is not a collection; it's a dictionary.

A collection would be:

```json
[{"charge":"5","start_count":"10","status":"Completed","remains":"90","currency":"USD"},{"charge":"8","start_count":"50","status":"Completed","remains":"50","currency":"USD"},{"charge":"7","start_count":"80","status":"Completed","remains":"20","currency":"USD"}]
```

The differences are:

- A collection is enclosed in `[]` brackets, whereas dictionary is an object `{}`.
- A collection has keyless objects: `[{},{},{}]`, a dictionary requires key-value pair for every object: `{"": {}, "": {}, "": {}}`

TL:DR; Deserialise your JSON into `Dictionary<int, Entity>`, where `Entity` is an item of your mongoDB collection.

Comment: The JSON object is the response of an API. Is it possible to extract the content from the collection from every single order ID and parse out the values I need without deserializing it into a dictionary? This needs to be automated bc new order id's are added automatically and the response always changes. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How would you like to filter out values without deserialising? RegEx?

Comment: Not necessarily without deserialising, but simply so that it extracts the required values ​​with the associated order ID for each order ID in the response

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue myself, I just had to create a loop through the response and extract the single values, here is the code:

```
JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

foreach (var order in responseObject)
{
    string orderID = order.Key;
    string orderStartCount = order.Value["start_count"].ToString();
    string orderStatus = order.Value["status"].ToString();
    string orderRemains = order.Value["remains"].ToString();

    
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("orderID", orderID);
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", orderStatus)
                                             .Set("start_count", orderStartCount)
                                             .Set("remains", orderRemains);
    MyCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
}
```